# Every interior point is an accumulation point. (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that every point in $X^0$ is an accumulation point of $X^0$ where $X$ is a non-empty set in $\mathbb{C}$.

I wanted to prove this with a contradiction using the fact every point in an arbitrary non-empty subset of $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is either an isolated point or an accumulation point of $A$.

So, I thought letting some $y \in X^0$ be an isolated point would give me a contradiction, but I am stuck.

Here's my work.

Assume that some point $y \in X^0$ is an isolated point.

Since $y$ is an isolated point of the open set $X^0$,
$\exists \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B(y,\epsilon) \cap X^0 = {y}$ and $B(y,\epsilon) \subseteq X^0$.

Consider $X^0\setminus \{y\}$.

$X^0 \setminus \{y \} = X^0 \setminus B(y,\epsilon)$

But, I can't take further steps from here because if $X^0 = \{ y\}=B(y,\epsilon)$, we only get $X^0 \setminus B(y,\epsilon) = \emptyset$, then we can't show that $\exists x \neq y$ in $X^0 \setminus \{y\}$ to construct a sequence that converges to $y$ (which tells us $y$ is an accumulation point of $X^0$ at the same time.)

Since my assumption "$X^0 = \{ y\}=B(y,\epsilon)$" doesn't give me any contradiction, it must mean it is a wrong assumption. But, I can't think of any reason for this.
Can I get some help with this?

Comment: What is $X^0$ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson $X^0$ is the interior of $X$

Comment: In the line "Since $y$ is an isolated point...", what you wrote down implies that $y$ is an exterior point. And definition of isolated point can't include the condition that $B(y,\epsilon) \subset X^0$?

Comment: @AVP82000 That is the idea of the proof. I wanted to assume the wrong thing so that contradictions can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "if $\{y\}=B(y,\varepsilon)$...", but that can't happen no matter how small $\varepsilon$ is. Check this against the definition of $B$, and then rethink your approach.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked the definition. So, basically, it is a set of points that are near $y$ within the distance of $\epsilon$, but I wonder what if $X^0 = {y}$. I've also considered the discrete set. Can $X^0$ ever be a discrete set? (which should be somewhat similar to my assumption)

Comment: @john You wrote in your question "the open set $X^0$". Do you have reason to believe $X^0$ is open? If so, could $X^0$ be a singleton or discrete? If you don't have reason to believe $X^0$ is open, think about the definition of interior, and what it would mean for there to be a point $y\in X^0$.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked them. And, I also found this from another mathstack answer "A (nonempty) discrete set cannot be open in ℂ, because an open set is one containing an open ball, and the points inside the open ball clearly do not have the discrete topology." So, may I assume that any open ball in $\mathbb{C}$ is fully filled?

Comment: @john There are many approaches and definitions to these things, so you can't rely on definitions/facts you find in other answers if you're trying to build an argument from the standpoint of your book/class etc. A *ball* $B(y,\varepsilon)$ is probably "fully filled" by the definition in your source. But what you can say about interiors or open sets depends sensitively on the definition/facts you have available in your source.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!